# What causes Windows security logs saying an attempt was made to reset an account's password?

Tags: windows, powershell, log-analysis, windows-7

This falls under the category of eliminating what might be normal activity from my attention.

I'm looking at Windows 7 security event logs.  I don't have context to know if the following event is a normal occurrence.  It happens 10 times a day or more on my workstation.  What is causing it?

[image: Powershell get_eventLog security log output]

Same events in event viewer look like this:

[image: security logs from event viewer]

Answer (score 1):

I just audited the event logs of all workstations in my environment (about 2000 windows 10, 4000 windows 7).

None had that error message in the last 3 days.

It's definitely not a normal occurrence. Do you have any 3rd party password management or MFA/2FA login devices for AD?

I'd post a comment but for some reason you need more points to comment than to answer. Sorry :(

Comment: interesting.  we checked my co-worker's results and he doesn't have them either

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, the responsible account for the success reset is the machine account itself (*5061$). And it is attempting to reset what seems to be a local account as the subject name equals the target domain name.

What comes to my mind when I see that, it'is the **password manager solution from Microsoft named LAPS**. Do you have this in place in your domain ? Or as Ghawblin saids, to you have any PAM solution in place ?